# Given coordinates of square, calculate new coordinates if diagonal is multiplied by factor n

Tags: python

As above: I'm trying to draw a bounding box. Given the x and y coordinates of the two opposite points that form a box, I'm trying to implement a function that multiplies the diagonal of that box by an arbitrary multiplier, then compute the new x and y coordinates. x and y can be positive or negative floats.

```
def return_box(x1, x2, y1, y2, multiplier = n):
  do_magic()
  return new_x, new_y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep (x1, y1) in the same place, scale the diagonal and return the new (x2, y2):

```
def return_box(x1, x2, y1, y2, multiplier = n):
  return (
    x1 + multiplier * (x2 - x1),
    y1 + multiplier * (y2 - y1)
  )
```

If you instead want to keep the center of the rectangle in the same place and return the two new corners:

```
def return_box(x1, x2, y1, y2, multiplier = n):
  xmid = (x1 + x2) / 2
  ymid = (y1 + y2) / 2
  return (
    xmid + multiplier * (x1 - xmid),
    ymid + multiplier * (y1 - ymid),
  ), (
    xmid + multiplier * (x2 - xmid),
    ymid + multiplier * (y2 - ymid)
  )
```

Comment: But if I plug in two points of (-2, 2) and (2, -2) and n=2 for example, the resulting point I would expect is (4,-4) or (-4,4). Your algorithm yields (-6,6).

Comment: Maybe I understood the question wrong, but I assumed n=2 means you want to double the size of the diagonal and keep (x1, y1) in the same place. I edited my answer to include a second case.